# How to install Portfolio Demo application on WIndows 64 bit

Tags: cassandra

I downloaded Community Edition MSi 64 bit Datastax Cassandra bundle and OPS Dashboard working but not sure how to get portfolio demo application working on windows? I downloaded tar bundle but that's for linux not for windows. Please suggest, it is urgent for me. Thanks Chandra

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try installing cygwin. However, the demos are (to my knowledge) only supported for Unix.